# Esper: how to react instantly to an over temperature, and also snapshot every 30 seconds?

Tags: java, esper

**TL;DR**

I'm trying to create an Esper query that:

- Reacts instantly to an over temperature in a room;
- Outputs a snapshot of all room temperatures every 30 seconds.

---

### Snapshot feature works fine...

- So far, I have the snapshot working every 30 seconds.
- The only thing missing is to make it instantly publish if any room's
  temperature rises above 35 degrees celsius (so we do not have to wait until the scheduled snapshot).
- I've read through [all of the documentation](http://www.espertech.com/esper/documentation.php), but just can't figure out how to do this properly.

---

Esper query so far:

```
// Schema for IncomingRoomTemperatures:
//   double temperatureCelsius
//   string roomDescription

// Intent: Input from Java.
CREATE WINDOW RoomTempaturesThrottled.std:unique(roomDescription) 
              as SELECT * FROM IncomingRoomTemperature;

INSERT INTO RoomTempaturesThrottled
SELECT
    *
FROM IncomingRoomTemperature r
WHERE r.temperatureCelsius >= 35;

// Intent: Output to Java.
@Name('room-temperatures-throttled')
SELECT * FROM RoomTempaturesThrottled
OUTPUT SNAPSHOT EVERY 10 SECONDS;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing more needed than this:

```
// react if any room's temperature rises above 35 degrees celsius.
SELECT * FROM IncomingRoomTemperature(temperatureCelsius >= 35)
```

Comment: ... which is the same as SELECT * FROM IncomingRoomTemperature where temperatureCelsius >= 35

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I also need to send a complete snapshot of all room temperatures every 30 seconds. I might have to look at combining two streams - one snapshot,  and one that reacts instantly when the room temperature crosses the 35 degree threshold.

Comment: You already posted a solution to the snapshot question so what is the remaining question.

Comment: The only thing missing is to make it instantly publish if any room's temperature rises above 35 degrees celsius (so we do not have to wait until the scheduled snapshot).

Comment: This already instantly calls when IncomingRoomTemperature comes in that matches. What you do with it i.e. "publish it" is your code if you will.